# Can’t access the admin page on a TP-LINK TD-W8961ND

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a [TP-LINK TD-W8961ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/TD-W8961ND.html) ADSL router/modem. I connect through `PPPoE LLC Encapsulation`.

I set it up for the first time, and everything worked well for about a month (during which I updated the firmware to the latest version).

Last week I decided to change ISPs, but then when I wanted to change the user/pass, I went to `http://192.168.1.1`, and saw nothing. I tried giving different addresses - although I haven't changed it the first time—to no avail.

After hard resetting it, I could access the admin page and put my new credentials. It worked well with the new credentials for about four days but then the connection was lost. I wanted to see what's up via the admin page, but again it wouldn’t let me access the admin page so I had to hard reset it again.

What's causing this? How can I solve it?

Comment: Do you connect to your router via an Ethernet cable or wirelessly? If wirelessly, then your problem may be that your wireless connection is dropping. If you experience this problem with a cabled connection, I would return the router to the shop and ask them to replace it. Having your router lose connection after 4 days uptime is not acceptable.

Comment: @Kristian Please refer to the comment on Billy_Bob answer

Answer (score 6):

it is a bug in TD-8961, 8951 and other versions of TP-Link ADSL wifi routers.

I have a TP-Link TD-8961ND V3 and it has the same problem. Every time you restart the device you can access the Admin Web portal, but after 24 hours (sometimes more) you loose the access. The WEB, Telnet and SNMP access to the device are rejected.

Updating firmware did not solve the problem. Currently with  Firmware Version Build 140305 Rel.04531

The only solution is to reset or power cycle the device.

There are many reports of this problem in TP-Link forums but it has not been adressed by the manufacturer.

I have to add that internet access through the device is not affected, only the management functions.

I had to install a remotely controlled relay to restart the router in case i need to remotely help my parents to troubleshoot wifi problems.

Answer (score -2):

check this

http://mis.fortunecook.ie/misfortune-cookie-suspected-vulnerable.pdf

suspected vulnerability affecting tp link admin

Comment: Do not view this PDF file outside of a sandbox. The author's router isnt even listed in the document

Comment: @Ramhound although my device **is** listed in there, it's really not related to what cause the problem in the first place.
This vulnerability is mainly exploit for stealing/monitoring, not to damage the equipment.

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar problem on the wireless. After I changed `interface setup-wireless:Wireless Mode` to `802.11b+g`, the problem was resolved.