# Can't telnet to router

Tags: networking, router, telnet

I have a TP-Link TD-w8961 router and I'm trying to connect to it using telnet. I've tried this command: `telnet 192.168.1.1` but it times out. I've also tried connecting to port 80 and i get the following result `Connected to 192.168.1.1. Escape character is '^]'`. Then it hangs there, until the connection gets closed by the remote host. It doesn't even ask me for a password. Do you know why? Thanks

Comment: Port 80 is the web interface, so you need to open in a browser, not in `telnet`. Check your firewall settings to make sure that you can connect to the telnet port (23), and that this port is open on the router (`nmap 192.168.1.1`).

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/a/947956/772515

Comment: MichaelBay no it's not related. I've updated my router's firmware and that problem it's now fixed. The only port open in the router is 80. How do i open port 23? I know that port forwarding isn't the way because it won't let me forward a port on 192.168.1.1

Comment: I have the same problem, there is no tick box to enable Telnet in the web interface, and I get a timeout when I do `telnet 192.168.0.1` (I don't know why the router chose 0.1 instead of 1.1 actually but that's another topic). nmap on 192.168.0.1  shows: `23/tcp   filtered   telnet`. Should it be `open` instead of `filtered`?

Answer (score 1):

Use your browser to connect to the router then log in as the admin. Go to Management, Access Control, Remote Access. There is a tick box there to enable Telnet. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually there's no tick box there. Here is a screenshot. I've tried to enable telnet by adding it to the table but no luck, still the same result
https://imgur.com/a/YTQjb (sorry if it is in italian)

Comment: try 0000-0000 isntead of 192-1568.1.1-192.168.1.1